# How can I symbolicate a call stack in react-native (expo, metro, storybook)

Tags: react-native, expo, stack-trace, storybook, metro-bundler

[ios simulator screenshot - console warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rZ8Y.png)

When running my react-native application on the iOS Simulator, in the Console Warning, I cannot view the source as the message says:

> This call stack is not symbolicated. Some features are unavailable such as viewing the function name or tapping to open files.

The react-native docs on symbolication are not really helpful in my case, as I cannot see how they relate ([react-native/symbolication](https://reactnative.dev/docs/symbolication))

What I need, is a view of the source of the problem like in this attached screenshot

[iOS Simulator with readable source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3bp.png) (source: [github/react-native-community/issue-69](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/69) )

Is there anything I can change in my configs/project or is that just wishful thinking?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Leo Clarke Were you able to figure it out? I'm running into the same issue, on iOS Simulator with debug builds.